# I want to use dynamic progressbar when the data fetch from excel sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to insert progress bar(bootstrap).while the the data is fetching from excel sheet to drop down list box its taking around 5 seconds .till that I want progress bar to fill the webpage.give some idea .

Comment: what you tried? please share your approach

Comment: I have one drop down list box its fetching data from excel sheet ,its taking around 5sec .till that time I need some UI performance like (progress bar or  loading image) so that webpage wont stand still.

Comment: share your code please

Comment: Sry tiwari I cant able to share the code there is a restriction

Answer (score 0):

```
I guess you are looking for some preloader shown on your page when an event gets triggered..I have written a piece code where you can achieve that..
```

View:

```
<ul id="prloader" style="display:none">
<li>
<img src="~/images/loader.gif" /></li>
<li id="msg">Processing. Please Wait...</li>
</ul>
```

Jquery(If you using ajax call):

```
 $('****').change(function(){        //You can have any other event based on your requirement..

  $('#prloader').show();

  $.ajax({
  url:"../../Controller/Action",
  success:function(response){

   //Have your logic here


   $('#prloader').hide();

  },
  error:function(){

  $('#prloader').hide();

  }
  });
 });
```

Comment: Is that what you have asked for... !!

Comment: I didn't get exactly which I need but I got an idea